# Haskell, How to define Module?

Tags: haskell, module

I wrote a very simple program in Haskell, which takes two list and it merges.
But I don't understand how to define Module in Haskell.

Hier is my Code

```
module Merge(Merge (empty, list)merge) where ....
merge::[a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:(merge xs ys)
```

I do not know, what I should after "where" write.
Only listoperations for example head tail etc. or?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: after `where` comes the code of the module.  ie the functions and datatypes of the module.  If you need to import anything that comes after the "where" but before the rest of the code.  Is this a question of syntax or what functions you should write?

Comment: @puhlen Ich have only this function und I need module for this function.  Is it this part corect?  `module Merge(Merge (empty, list)merge)`

Comment: @Haskell: but here you only have the `merge` function, so `module Merge(merge) where`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [*Haskell '10 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html) shows a sample program:

> ```
> module Main where  
>   import A  
>   import B  
>   main = A.f >> B.f  
>
> module A where  
>   f = ...  
>
> module B where  
>   f = ...
> ```
>
> It is equivalent to the following single-module program:
>
> ```
> module Main where  
>   main = af >> bf  
>
>   af = ...  
>
>   bf = ...
> ```

After the `where` one writes import statements, class declarations, function declarations, etc.

One can also write a list of exports between parenthesis. These exports are functions, classes, types, constructors, etc.

Using `where` to enter a scope is not specific to modules. The same happens when we define the functions of a `class`, or function definitions in an `instance`.

In your code, you only define a `merge` function, and do not import anything, so it is likely that the code file should look like:

```
module Merge(merge) where

merge::[a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:(merge xs ys)
```